# Subclipse ignores "Accept Permanently" when "Accept Digital Certificate" dialog is shown

Tags: eclipse, macos, svn, subclipse

Under Eclipse running on OS X I have been running into issues with Subclipse ignoring "Accept Permanently" when the "Accept Digital Certificate" dialog is shown when updating or committing to the repository. How can this issue be resolved so that the dialog does not appear every time I interact with the repository?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Best thing to do is to just make Subversion reconfigure itself and the way to do this is as follows:

1. Close Eclipse and any programs that might be using Subversion.
2. Open the terminal and go to you home directory (i.e. ~).
3. Remove the `.subversion` directory (i.e. `rm -rf .subversion`).
4. Restart Eclipse and update your local repository, you will be prompted to accept the certificate. Once accepted it should be stored and you should be good to go.

Comment: BTW: on Windows7 corresponding data is in directory similar to this:
c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth
Just erase it's content and restart Eclipse.

Comment: The path that worked for me on Windows XP was:

C:\Users\\AppData\Subversion\auth